# Styling android Listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

### I am trying to style my `Listview` in android

---

**What I want to do**:: I want to get a background color and the text color of the `listview`  as shown in figure below

**[Edit]**
I also want a custom click effect on selecting row

[image]

**What i currently have**:: A simple listview that is developed using the base adapter

**My current listview Snapshot**::

[image]

---

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ImageTextListBaseAdapterActivity.java**

```
public class ImageTextListBaseAdapterActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
        "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };

    public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
        "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
        "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
    "Mixed Fruits" };

    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four };

    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>



    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

### How can i achieve my goal to obtain my ,listview as shown in the first snapshot

Comment: set background on listview for background and set textColor for text.

Comment: @Manmohan .... Please see the edit .... i also trying to get a click effect on list selection

Comment: u can set a xml for background as well as we use for button for diff effects on click /focus/default

Comment: @Manmohan .... Please can you show me a sample as your answer ?

Comment: Here you are a nice [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) and [another one](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.it/p/android-image-listview.html)... just a quickie with Google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to have the background like the one you have mentioned:

Your list row xml should be like :

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relId"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/txt"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="@color/blue_color_here"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S: define the blue_color_here,in the color file (color.xml resource file)

Also, pass this layout in the custom adapter and use this in order to fill the items into the list.

For click effects, create a drawable and set the background of the listSelector to the drawable and also the background of the relative layout to the drawable.

the drawable could look like:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/when_pressed"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Comment: Thanks u [+1] .... for the info .... Also can u Edit your answer with a custom selector for list row selection .... which i have mentioned in second question